# ComboBox Behavior

Tags: .net, combobox, desktop

When presenting a fixed list of countries in a ComboBox control, with no free text entry, the user expectation is that if they begin spelling out the name of the country, it will take them to that country name.  Instead, the default behavior is for it to move to the first item in the list that begins with that character. So, when they hit the second character of the name, it takes them to the first country beginning with that letter.

For example, if I press "S" a bunch of times, it lets me scroll through all of the countries beginning with "S" to get to Singapore. If I press "S", "I", "N", it takes me the first country starting with "S", then the first country starting with "I", then the first country starting with "N". I'd rather have "S", "I", "N" take me to countries beginning with "Sin"

Is there an easy way to enable that latter behavior?

Comment: Think twice before you do this. As unfortunate as it is, it's standard behavior, and anybody who's learned how it works everywhere else will be frustrated by your system. For example I know to hit M 5 times whenever I see a State field, because that will bring up Minnesota.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, except that my user population has been using a VB application for the past ten years that works that way. So, they are expecting it. Since they live in the application about 6-8 hours per day, they get used to it and complain about how the rest of the world works.

Comment: Surely typing Mi is faster than having to press M 5 times. Microsoft themselves seem to mix it. Outlook uses the default system, visual studio the second one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this by setting the following properties on the combobox

```
AutoCompleteMode = Suggest
AutoCompleteSource = ListItems
DropDownStyle = DropDownList
```

Now, they can't be slacking and typing real slow...but if they type at a reasonable speed it will jump down to what they need.

If they are slow, it will behave like you mentioned

Comment: Is there a way to get past the speed problem?